# cURL no url specified

Tags: curl, ibm-cloud, speech-to-text

I am following this tutorial to set up a speech to text service in IBM Bluemix:
https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/speech-to-text/tutorial.shtml

I have installed and tested the prerequisites, but somehow I get an error when I try to enter:

```
curl -X POST -u <username>:<password>
--header "Content-Type: audio/flac"
--header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked"
--data-binary @<path>audio-file.flac
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?continuous=true"
```

I got following error:

```
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

I've tested the username and password when I was directly accessing the url and it worked. The path I've entered for the audio file is also correct since I just copied it.

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Is everything entered as single command?

Comment: No, I paste it into Cmder in once

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the escapes for new lines. Try something like this:

```
curl -X POST -u "myusername":"mypassword" \
--header "Content-Type: audio/flac" \
--data-binary "@audio-file1.flac" \
--data-binary "@audio-file2.flac" \
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?timestamps=true&word_alternatives_threshold=0.9&keywords=%22colorado%22%2C%22tornado%22%2C%22tornadoes%22&keywords_threshold=0.5&continuous=true"
```

[Sample Audio Files](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/speech-to-text/api/v1/audio-files.zip)

Comment: Sorry, somehow I got no recognition that you've answered :P 
But it tells me: "curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '\'"

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: You could also get rid of those escape characters and post it as a single one-liner.

Comment: Yes, I am using windows 7 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I forgot the double quotes when I was entering the path. But now it returns this HTML Code:

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Network Error</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big><strong></strong></big><BR>
</FONT>
<blockquote>
<TABLE border=0 cellPadding=1 width="80%">
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big>Network Error (tcp_error)</big>
<BR>
<BR>
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
A communication error occurred: "Connection refused"
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica" SIZE=2>
<BR>
For assistance, contact your network support team.<br><br>Your request was categorized by Blue Coat Web Filter as 'Technology/Internet'. <br>If you wish to question or dispute this result, please click <a href="http://sitereview.bluecoat.com/sitereview.jsp?referrer=136&url=http://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?continuous=true">here</a>.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
</blockquote>
</FONT>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: it's not clear whether you have another issue, so you may not get a response. If this is a new issue, your best bet is to post a new question based on your new problem scenario.